# How to check if libraries from requirements.txt is installed or not during python package unpackaging

Tags: json, python-3.x, package

I am building a pypi tool which will auto-install python libraries from json file and `print` if installation is done or not.
This is my `setup.py` file:

```
import setuptools
import pip
from subprocess import call
for package in 'requirements':
    try:
        call("pip install "+package, shell=True)
        print("Install success")
    except:
        print("Install failed for "+package)    
with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()
    fh.close()
setuptools.setup(
    name="json123",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="hari",
    author_email="hari@gmail.com",
    description="Auto install of python packages",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    classifiers=["Programming Language :: Python :: 3",],
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    py_package=['json123'],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        json123=json123:main
    ''',
    )
```

json123.py is script which will take "dependencies" from json file and copy it to requirements.txt( requirements.txt is created by this program)

```
import json
def main():
    f = open( "package.json" , "rb" )
    d = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    with open("requirements.txt", "w+") as fb:
        for i,j in zip(d["dependencies"].keys(), d["dependencies"].values()):
            line = "{}=={}\n".format(i, j.strip("^"))
            fb.writelines(line)
    fb.close()
```

I have also included `MANIFEST.in`, `README.md`, `package.json`(source) and `requirements.txt` along with above mentioned files.
For execution:

```
pip install -e . -r requirements.txt
```

`-e .` to install locally and `-r requirements.txt` to install mentioned libraries. When I executed it package got installed:

```
Obtaining file:///C:/Users/ha/json123
Installing collected packages: json123
Running setup.py develop for json123
Successfully installed json123
```

It isn't getting installed as required.

Comment: What does `pip list -l | grep json123` output?